# ReferenceError: WScript is not defined

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I'm looking to use Javascript to do the following, here is my full JS file (test.js):

```
var xo = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
var xa = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");

try {

xo.open("GET", "http://iso.x20host.com/www/successAlert.vbs", false);
xo.send();

xa.write(xo.responseBody);
xa.saveToFile("C:\success.vbs", 2)

} catch (er) {

console.log(er);

};
```

But, I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: WScript is not defined

Do I need to reference this, somehow? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What environment are you trying to do this in? Looks like old Windows Script Host stuff. If you're trying to do it in a browser, it's not going to work. The XHR stuff you can do with `XMLHttpRequest`. You can't save a file to the user's filesystem though.

Comment: I just tried running the js file instead of opening it through a browser. I get no error once I remove the console.log(er); line since it was complaning about that. For some reason it's not writing anything to C:\ like that. Any idea why, or how I would debug it (ie. see what's being returned from xo, if anything)?

Answer (score 1):

1. `WScript` is an object provided by the W|CScript.exe hosts; IExplorer or MSHTA don't provide it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915571/603855)).
2. `Console`is an object provided by (some) browsers. A script runninng under C|WScript.exe can use `WScript.Echo` instead.
3. You need to open and type-specify a stream before you can write to it.
4. Use MSHTA.Exe/An .HTA file if you want a GUI **and** access to the local filesystem.

(Working) Console Demo script

```
var xo = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
var xa = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");

try {

xo.open("GET", "http://iso.x20host.com/www/successAlert.vbs", false);
xo.send();

xa.open();
xa.type = 1;
xa.write(xo.responseBody);
xa.saveToFile(".\success.vbs", 2)

} catch (er) {

  // console.log(er);
  WScript.Echo(er, er.message);

};
```

Comment: Not a fan of not defining named constants, no need for unfriendly code like `xa.Type = 1`. Why wouldn't you use the [`StreamTypeEnum` constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675277(v=vs.85).aspx)? Should define `Const adTypeBinary = 1` and replace the line with `xa.Type = adTypeBinary`.

Comment: Same goes for [`SaveOptionsEnum` constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676152(v=vs.85).aspx) as well for `SaveToFile()`.