# IBM Pcomm Macro - Error when trying to use WScript.Shell

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Hope you can help.

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

Dim ShellObj : Set ShellObj = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ShellObj.Run("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
```

Error I am getting is that "WScript" is not defined... I have already tried defining and as expected it still didn't work.

What I am trying to achieve is opening CMD directly from the personal communications session. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be special considerations needed for PCOMM, but I believe that just removing the WScript in

```
Dim ShellObj : Set ShellObj = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

so it reads

```
Dim ShellObj : Set ShellObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

will solve the problem by avoiding the (un-neccessary) reference to the `WScript` object that is provided by the `C|WScript.exe` scripting hosts only. For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915571/603855).