# Call VBScript from C# with WScript access

Tags: c#, vbscript

C# code with COM MSScriptControl:

```
var script = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
script.Language = "VBScript";
script.AddObject("me", this, true);
//script.AddObject("WScript", wscript, true);
script.AddCode(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Script.vbs"));
```

Script.vbs content:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
```

Error : Objet requis: 'WScript'

How I can create an instance of WScript object in C# for addobject ?

Comment: The WScript object is implemented by wscript.exe and cscript.exe, they are no longer in the picture.  It is now you that implements the host, you therefore have to implement WScript as well.  This doesn't have to be difficult, but it can be if you want to support everything that WScript does.  All you are asking for is a C# class that is [ComVisible(true)] with a public object CreateObject(string progid, string prefix) method.  Call Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(progid).  The WScript.Quit() method is notably hard to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need/can't give the WScript object provided by the wscript.exe/cscript.exe hosts to the ScriptControl. Just use plain `CreateObject`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915571/603855).